# Refresh a div with ajax and rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Trying to use ajax to refresh a div on the page (a list of products).

I have this `refresh.js.erb` file:

```
console.log("in the refresh.js.erb file");
console.log('<%=j @products.inspect %>');

<% new_html ="" %>

console.log('after the loop');
console.log('<%=j new_html%>');   //This line gives me problems, and I don't think I can solve 'em.
```

When I have all those lines in there (except the last one), it prints out stuff in my console, but the last one causes nothing to get printed out.

1. what am I doing wrong?
2. how do I even trouble shoot this since it wont print to the console? Is there another place to check for errors?

Comment: You should see in web tools of your browser what the outputted JavaScript looks like. The `<%=j new_html%>` will probably be replaced with something that will make the whole syntax invalid such as single '.

Comment: That was it... the 'j' function. I am going to have to create a loop to get a partial for each product. Is that even posible?

Comment: In general, I would recommend you to look into something like [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to format the **data** you are sending instead of passing some actual JavaScript. This way you can just ask for the data and handle it as you wish in your client application.

Comment: After looking at jbuilder, I'm not sure how to implement it. The page in question needs to have html not json on it. I'm able to send the updated `@products` to the `js.erb` file (as a response to the ajax call), but can jbuilder update the page?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the controller method that is sending your `new_html` to the js render